# Read 50% of a table excluding the last row

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am reading an Excel that has more than a million records and 29 columns, I read this Excel as if it were a table in Microsoft SQL Server.

```
select * from [file $]
```

This table has only categorical fields, amounts and dates, it has no unique id or incremental fields (I can't create or edit the table). Due to the large amount of data, I have the need to read it in 2 blocks.

How can I read the 1st 50% and then the other 50%

I am testing with:

```
select top (50) percent * 
from [file $] 
order by name asc
```

followed by:

```
select top (50) percent * 
from [file $] 
order by name desc
```

But the last row would be repeating itself, how could I exclude it?

I have read that in some cases it does not return the data correctly.

I'm considering 2 blocks of 50%, but they can be any number. I just have to make sure that the information is complete.

Any comment will be of great help.

Thank you,

Comment: Specifically, why do you need to read it in two blocks?

Comment: hello, they could also be in more blocks no problem. I just want the integrity of the information to be maintained. If you have any idea you can share it with me. Thank you,

Comment: Your question mentions SQL Server and Excel.  Your question is tagged SQLite.  Please tag only with the tool you are really using.

Comment: What specifically is the issue with reading in one big block?

Comment: The short answer is - you can't. You have no unique key so it is impossible to formulate a query that will not read the same rows.

Comment: Can you split the data into multiple excel files?

Comment: "Due to the large amount of data, I have the need to read it in 2 blocks.". Please explain that actual issue you are having - error message? performance?

Comment: you mentioned you cant edit the table, but could you use Power Query to copy/query the data into another worksheet and add in Row Number or an ID field?

Comment: Hello thanks for the answers, what I did was read it with vb.net by blocks, like this: select * from [file1 $ a3: 500000] then [5000001: 1000000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello thanks for the answers, what I did was read it with vb.net by blocks, like this: select * from [file1 $ a3: 500000] then [5000001: 1000000]